# How to add github project into xcode swift project

Tags: xcode, swift, github

I've got an existing Swift project in Xcode and I want to use the functionality of this github project ([MangoKitten](https://github.com/PlanTeam/MongoKitten.git))

They suggest using Swift Package Manager but when I tried setting up that my Xcode went haywire and would crash every time I tried launching it.

So I've finally managed to undo the damage done from SPM and am trying to just go ahead and add MangoKitten into my project manually so that I can use the functionality it provides with a simple import statement in my viewController.swift

I've never used Github before and I'm relatively new to Swift in general so this is all very confusing.

Is there any simple way to import the github project into my Xcode project without downloading it and adding every single .swift file manually into my project?

Thanks guys.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to download the source and manually include it in your project. The Swift package manager has not been integrated into Xcode yet, it's still in development however I think SPM can generate Xcode project files for you (not 100% sure that functionality is complete)

Comment: Ok I've added all the .swift files from the Github project into my project. But there is a line in the github read that says to do import MongoKitten but no .swift file is named MongoKitten... How would I create the item?

Comment: AFAIK, if you add all the files into your project, it would be in your module. so there's no need to `import`. The reason why there's no `MogoKitten.swift` is that `MongoKitten` is the name of the module.

Comment: Gotcha you were right.  However in one of the .swift files is an import BSON statement which is causing an error because it can't find a BSON module.  Not sure how to fix this since none of the .swifts have BSON names.